# Как правильно: "со школы" или "из школы"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

"Дорога со школы домой" или "дорога из школы домой"?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: дорога из школы домой.

Дорога из школы домой в эти дни стала удивительно длинной (А. И. Мусатов).

Сравнить: Придет со школы и всё рассказывает как и что там было (разговорно-просторечный вариант).

Предлог СО в этом случае имеет значение времени:

Со школы, а то и с детского сада, начинает выстраиваться глобальная система страхов (нейтральный стиль).

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: из школы. Чтобы не путаться, надо разобраться в сочетаемости предлогов.

В - из. Пошел в школу, пришел из школы.

На - с. Пошел на концерт, пришел с концерта.

Comment: При выборе  нужной пары предлогов можно пользоваться эмпирическим правилом, в соответствии с которым предмет представляется в виде плоскости (предлог НА)  или объема (предлог В): пойти в театр, на каток, на стадион. Отвлеченные понятия, как правило, пространственным свойством не обладают: пойти на концерт.

Comment: Вера, дело в не в отвлеченности. Если при выборе направления  объекта мы употребляем предлог «на» , то  сообщая о возвращении объекта, следует употребить предлог «с» . Это простое сочетание предлогов.  Эмпирическом правило, о котором вы говорите, может лишь запутать.Всякий раз придется думать: а какое значение имеет предлог: плоскости или объема. Ср. пойти в театр, но: на кухню, на почту( здесь нет ни плоскости, ни отвлеченности).

Comment: Да никто не возражает по поводу  приведенных Вами пар предлогов, это всё правильно, речь о другом. Если вам не нравится предлагаемое эмпирическое правило ( правило-наблюдение),  тогда заучивайте наизусть все варианты с этими предлогами.  Но чем-то должна объясняться традиция выбора, странно, что вам это неинтересно. А "запутаться" тоже иногда полезно, это развивает мышление и чувство языка. Я, собственно,  в этом комментарии обращаюсь к думающей категории пользователей, не к тем, которые боятся запутаться.

Comment: И по поводу кухни и почты: возможно эти предметы раньше не воспринимались как комнатка в 10 метров или  помещение на нижнем этаже многоэтажки, где принимают посылки.

Comment: Вера, насчет кухни и почты, вы абсолютно правы. Я лишь пишу о том, что если человек сомневается, какой предлог выбрать -  из - с, достаточно знать простое правило сочетания предлогов, которое не такое уж и трудное.